# loop to create output files with specific file names and content based on condition where name will be same as row content

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

i have a file with n # of rows. I am reading the file and assigning it to a dataframe `df`. One of the columns name is `curr_state`. Based on the `curr_state`, I would like to create different output files for each specific `curr_state`. The output files have to follow a specific name convention. I have done this individually with the below code:

```
#curr_state:  curr.state
#to extract rows that contain current state "curr.state"
CurrStateName= (df.loc[df['curr_state'] == 'curr.state'])

#naming convention
OutputCurrStateName = "abc_" +str(Client) + "_" + str(Channel) + "_" + "CurrStateName" + "_" + str(filedate) + ".csv"
#output file to a csv file
CurrStateName.to_csv(OutputCurrStateName, sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

However, I am looking to read another csv file containing the `curr_state` list and the `CurrStateName` corresponding to that `curr_state` and create the output files with the naming convention in a loop.

File containing the curr_state

```
curr_state.                 CurrStateName
hello.attempt             HelloAttempt
Goodbye.attempt      GoodbyeAttempt
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far and ask specific questions. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: @IonicSolutions, In my opinion, OP has included what they have tried. Certainly there is an attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamically named variables are not recommended. They are difficult to track, clutter the namespace, lead to errors. Instead, you can use a dictionary comprehension with `GroupBy`.

For example, utilising f-strings (Python 3.6+), and assuming you have specified strings `Client`, `Channel` and `filedate`:

```
d = {f'abc_{Client}_{Channel}_{state}_{filedate}': df_state \
     for state, df_state in df.groupby('curr_state')}
```

Then you can output CSV files via iterating your dictionary of dataframes:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    v.to_csv(f'{k}.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```